# $_POST undefined, and defined at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Ok I am at a crossroad here. For some reason I have a page that Can both see a certain $_POST index and cannot see it.

I am using a jquery script to load a div with the page here is my function.

```
function custom() {
    var type = getType();
    var start = $("#startdatepicker").val();
    var end = $("#enddatepicker").val();
    alert(type+start+end);
    $(".reports").load("fragments/report.php", { type: type, frame: "custom", start: start, end: end });
}
```

The alert in the function shows that each of my variables are set.

At the top of the page I put a foreach loop on my $_POST to log the contents of the array.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$post){
        error_log($key."--".$post);
    }
}
```

And I get this in my log

```
[Tue Nov 19 09:01:04 2013] [error] [client 10.20.30.83] type--program, referer: https://xxxxxxxx.local/report/Dashboard/?page=report
[Tue Nov 19 09:01:04 2013] [error] [client 10.20.30.83] frame--custom, referer: https://xxxxxxxx.local/report/Dashboard/?page=report
[Tue Nov 19 09:01:04 2013] [error] [client 10.20.30.83] start--11/11/2013, referer: https://xxxxxxxx.local/report/Dashboard/?page=report
[Tue Nov 19 09:01:04 2013] [error] [client 10.20.30.83] end--11/12/2013, referer: https://xxxxxxxx.local/report/Dashboard/?page=report
[Tue Nov 19 09:01:04 2013] [error] [client 10.20.30.83] start--11/11/2013, referer: https://xxxxxxxx.local/report/Dashboard/?page=report
[Tue Nov 19 09:01:04 2013] [error] [client 10.20.30.83] end--11/12/2013, referer: https://xxxxxxxx.local/report/Dashboard/?page=report
```

Notice that not only are my indexes there, but there is also an extra start and end index. Not sure why, but this is the least of my worries at this point.

Now further down that same report.php page on the same request. Like any other right minded coder I check if the index isset and it equals what I want it to (I already know it does), but the if statement doesn't pass it's conditional statement. I always get my fail string returned.

```
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=="program"){

}else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

If I remove the isset() condition, I get the undefined error for type.

I would also like to point out that in another jquery function I use the same line of code for load() minus the start and end parameters, and it works like a charm. And before it is suggested, yes, I did remove the start and end parameters from my failing instance, and this did not resolve the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here is my entire report.php. I am pretty sure I didn't redefine or empty $_POST.

```
    <?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$post){
        error_log($key."--".$post);
    }
}
if(empty($_POST)){
    echo "<div class=\"stale\">
        <p>
            <h3>
                <span>Select your parameters from the right.</span>
            </h3>
        </p>
    </div>";
}elseif(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=="rep"){
    require_once("../functions/reps.php");
    $frame=$_POST["frame"];
    if($frame=="week"){
        // get previouse week
    }elseif($frame=="month"){
        // get previouse month
    }elseif($frame=="ptd"){
        // get program to date
    }elseif($frame=="custom"){
        // get custom range
    }
}elseif(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=="program"){
    require_once("../functions/programs.php");
    $frame=$_POST["frame"];
    $groups=getGroups();
    $programs=getPrograms();

    if($frame=="week"){
        // get previouse week

        // totals
        // charts
        // tables
        echo "<div class=\"table-container\"><div class=\"custom-table\">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Program</td>
                    <td>Answered Calls</td>
                    <td>Abandoned Calls</td>
                    <td>Average Speed of Answer</td>
                    <td>Average Length of Calls</td>
                    <td>Average Wait Time</td>
                </tr>";

        foreach($groups as $group){
            $showGroup=false;
            foreach($programs as $program){
                $programGroup=$program["group_name"];
                $included=$program["calculate"];
                if($programGroup==$group && $included){
                    $showGroup=true;
                }
            }
            if($showGroup){
                echo "<tr>
                    <td class=\"groupname\" colspan=6>$group</td>
                </tr>";
            }

            foreach($programs as $program){
                $programName = $program["display"];
                $programGroup=$program["group_name"];
                $included=$program["calculate"];
                $id=$program["account_id"];
                if($programGroup==$group && $included){
                    $answered=getLastWeekAnsweredCalls($id);
                    $abandoned=getLastWeekAbandonedCalls($id);
                    $abandonedPercent=$abandoned/$answered*100;
                    echo "<tr>
                        <td>$programName</td>
                        <td>".$answered."</td>
                        <td>".$abandoned." (".round($abandonedPercent,2)."%)</td>
                        <td>".gmdate("H:i:s", getLastWeekASA($id))."</td>
                        <td>".gmdate("H:i:s", getLastWeekALC($id))."</td>
                        <td>".gmdate("H:i:s", getLastWeekACW($id))."</td>
                    </tr>";
                }
            }
        }
        echo "</table>
        </div></div>";


        // pivots
        // charts
        // tables
    }elseif($frame=="month"){
        // get previouse month
    }elseif($frame=="ptd"){
        // get program to date
    }elseif($frame=="custom"){
        $start=$_POST["start"];
        $end=$_POST["end"];
        // get custom range

        // totals
        // charts
        // tables


        // pivots
        // charts
        // tables
    }
    }else{
    echo "fail";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Something that confuses me is how you're getting a POST transaction. As far as I know, `$(foo).load()` will always do a GET.

Comment: @Pointy `The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.`, from [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Is it possible that you're sending two requests, and the first one does work but the second one doesn't? And because `$_POST` is empty on the second, nothing gets logged? Can you take a look at the outgoing requests in your browser's dev tools? Or add a log for all requests regardless of `$_POST` being set?

Comment: Unless your error_log unsets the POST this is indeed very weird. Can you please attach the entire report.php?

Comment: @qwertynl well I guess that makes sense then. (I haven't actually used `.load()` in a long time ... ) thanks

Comment: I had the same feature a couple of months ago. Read about synchronous and asynchronous calls. You can also find sources for asynchronous alerts on the web. If you use one of those you'll get undefined instead of defined.

Comment: What does `../functions/programs.php` contain? @EliteTech

Comment: @qwertynl it shouldn't matter that if statement should fail it's conditional statement and it never gets called. But at the moment it is a 0 bite file. Oh I see you changed the file. programs.php only contains functions for interacting with my database.

Comment: @EliteTech I updated my comment. We have no idea what all of your functions look like... This is looking like it might need some debugging on your side.

Comment: @qwerty I saw that and I updated my comment

Comment: Again -- We have no idea what all of your random functions look like, you should try to step through your code on a debugger to see what happens where. @EliteTech

Comment: I have never used a debugger with php, what do you recommend?

Comment: With all the code that I posted none of it was the problem. I was calling submit_form() when I clicked my button as well as my function. I removed the form DOM from my page and now it works. Sorry to waste all of your time. I will Answer my question once the time limit is lifted.

Comment: @qwertynl I would still like to know what you use for debugging php scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I was calling two function when I clicked on my submit button. I at one time was going to use a different way of handling this and forgot to remove the old way.

Here is the code where my button is.

```
<form method="POST" id="filter-form" onsubmit="submit_form();"> // This was the culprit
        <p>
            Start Date<input name="start" type="text" id="startdatepicker" />
        </p>
        <p>
            End Date<input name="end" type="text" id="enddatepicker" />
        </p>
        <button class="button" onclick="custom()">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Here is what it needed to be

```
<p>
        Start Date<input name="start" type="text" id="startdatepicker" />
    </p>
    <p>
        End Date<input name="end" type="text" id="enddatepicker" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <button class="button" onclick="custom()">Submit</button>
    </p>
</p>
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You should stop using onEvent functions and have a real javascript event handling. This is one of the reasons why.